# Python 2.7 Windows scripts not working in Unix

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, unix, redhat

I have a python script that I want to run in Redhat 6.7 OS but it is constantly failing.

**Python version: 2.7.13 (initially it had default version which I have symlink to usr/local/bin/python2.7, not sure if it has changed to 2.7 but when I type which is python in terminal it shows the location usr/local/bin/python.)

Script to be run on: OS = Redhat 6.7

Script written in: OS = Windows10 (python ver 2.7.11)

code:

```
import urllib
import json
url = 'https://username:pass@api.amsterdampc.com'# sample URL(tested on 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London' too gives the same error) 
data = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url)) #should return a json data
print data
```

Here print data is raising "json decoder error", when i looked back into the steps I found out urllib.urlopen(url) is not at all returning the required json data instead of some ml response/empty at times.

Is there any specific changes I need to do if I run a python script in different OS isn't python a platform independent language?

Comment: Sometimes the `\r\n` line endings from Windows can confuse on UNIX/Linux, so try converting with `dos2unix` - you might have to do that to the data files as well.

Comment: Is this _exactly_ your code (copied and pasted)? You've got an obvious syntax error that would generate a different message.

Comment: I think this fragment is repeated `url = 'https://` in the 3rd line.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Yes thanks for pointing out the error I have edited it

Comment: @cdarke I tried converting the file to dos2unix , but getting the same error
before running the script is executed dos2unix test.py and then python test.py

Comment: What is `api.amsterdampc.com`? I'm not getting an IP address for it (via `dig api.amsterdampc.com`).

Comment: @Chris URL is a sample URL since the URL which i am testing will not be accessible to you

Comment: @Rebbeca, it's nearly impossible to solve a problem when the question includes misleading errors (like the typo you fixed and the URL turning out to be fake). Please create an [mcve] so we can actually understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Chris I think URL has nothing to do with the problem I have asked,That is a type of URL I am using , It can be any API url returning an json response.
Since I have tried with other API urls too like
[link](api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London)
just I have to pass a authentication with this URL

Comment: @Rebbeca, that's not the point. _You **think**_ it has nothing to do with the problem. But how should _we **know**_ that it has nothing to do with it? All information needed to solve the problem should be included directly in your question. And make an effort to leave out misleading details like URLs that don't work. _Again_, please provide an [mcve]. Also read [ask].

Comment: I have pasted the edit can you help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By and large, python is *reasonably* platform independant. But that doesn't mean that there aren't differences between platforms. If you look through the documentation for the standard library, you will find notes that some functions or classes are only available on certain platforms. And e.g. the way `multiprocessing` works is also different between UNIX-like operating systems and ms-windows.

In this case you mention that the trouble begins with the fact that `urllib.urlopen` doesn't return what you expect. This is probably not an issue with the Python code. I *suspect* it is a networking/routing/firewall issue. You would have to show the returned not-JSON data to be sure.

As an aside, if you want to use HTML in Python, do yourself a favour and use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module. It is a lot more user-friendly then `urllib`.

**Edit 1**:

It says:

> Your request could not be processed. Request could not be handled
>
> This could be caused by a misconfiguration, or possibly a malformed request.

So there are two possible causes:

- misconfiguration
- malformed request

The network object returned by [`urllib.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) has some extra methods compared to files, like `info()` and `getcode()`. Using those might yield some extra information about why the request failed.

If you do a POST request, the information has to be formatted and encoded in a certain way. If you use `requests.post`, it will handle these details for you.

Comment: regarding using Requests module, it did not solve the problem.

Comment: if the issue belongs to networking/routing/firewall do I need to set any proxy inside the script?

Comment: @Rebbeca I didn't expect it to.

Comment: With regard to proxy settings *et cetera*, that is impossible for us to say until we see what is actually returned from the HTTP request.

Comment: added the response I am getting instead of json.
this sometimes also returns an empty response

Comment: So what do I do now to solve the Issue ?
urllib.getcode(url) is returning "no module named getcode"
also I have tried exporting a proxy export HTTPS_PROXY=proxy:8080 but it doesn't works too.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to give more detailed answers.

Comment: First of all, this problem seems at least partially a networking issue. Maybe a proxy configuration thing. In that case StackOverflow is the wrong forum. For example, I do not know anything about proxies. Second, networking issues are almost impossible to debug "from a distance". You will need someone knowledgable (maybe a colleague?) to sit with you at the machine and observe what happens. In general (as Chris commented) to get proper help from StackOverflow, you need to supply a minimal, comlete and *verifiable* example.

Comment: Hello Roland thanks for the help so far , I have identified the issue is with proxy 
I added the step 
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'https://my proxy:8080'
and it worked :-)